# column headers are corrupted when querying with pyodbc on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, unicode, pyodbc, unixodbc

I'm using postgres on ubuntu and use unixodbc and pyodbc 4.0.16 to access the data. I seem to have an issue related to unicode.
When querying the DB, the column headers appear to be corrupted.

Here's an example:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=local_postgres")

conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')

#conn.execute('create schema test')
conn.execute('create table test.uni_test(column1 varchar)')
conn.execute("insert into test.uni_test(column1) values ('My value')")

results = conn.execute('select * from test.uni_test')

print results.description
columns = [column[0].decode('latin1') for column in results.description]
print "columns: " + str(columns)
print list(results)

Result:
((u'c\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00', <type 'str'>, None, 255, 255, 0, True),)
columns: [u'c\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00']
[(u'My value', )]
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. 
BTW - exactly the same behavior is observed on my mac (el capitan).

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Perhaps try `conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-32le')` in addition to the `setdecoding` calls you already have.

Comment: Also, `print(conn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME) + ' ' + conn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_VER))` and tell us what it says.

Comment: Adding conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-32le') indeed resolved the issue!

Comment: For the record, the SQL_DRIVER_VER is:
psqlodbcw.so 09.06.0200

Answer (score 1):

`u'c\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00'` is the first 7 bytes of 'column1' in UTF-32LE encoding. (The value was apparently truncated at 7 bytes because 'column1' is 7 characters long.)

pyodbc received a significant upgrade to Unicode handling for its 4.x version, and one of the things that the developers discovered is the surprising variety of ways that ODBC drivers can mix-and-match encoding when returning values. The pyodbc Wiki page for Unicode recommends [the following for PostgreSQL ODBC under Python 2.7](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode#mysql-and-postgresql)

```python
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
```

but in this case the following was also required

```python
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-32le')
```